# JQuery Validating Check box Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to do a simple validate on my page with jquery. The top 'var a to e' values work fine but I have an issue with check boxes (var fa to ff) which must have at least one checked before the page submits. I've tried is checked, prop and bog-standard val (with true/false, 0, isnull etc) but all allow the page to be submitted rather than throwing up the #edialog message.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
function validateForm() {

var a = $('#Name').val();
var b = $('#Ward').val();
var c = $('#Job').val();
var d = $('#LDate').val();
var e = $('#Reason').val();

var fa = $('#MCHFT').prop('checked');
var fb = $('#ONHS').prop('checked');
var fc = $('#PSEC').prop('checked'); 
var fd = $('#PUBSEC').prop('checked');  
var fe = $('#EDU').prop('checked');
var ff = $('#NEMP').prop('checked'); 


if (a == null || a == "") {
  $('#EC1').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
}

if (b == null || b == "") {
  $('#EC2').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
}

if (c == null || c == "") {
  $('#EC3').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
}

if (d == null || d == "") {
  $('#EC4').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
}

 if (e == null || e == "") {
  $('#EC5').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
}


if (fa === "false" & fb === "false" || fb === "false"  || fc === "false" || fd === "false" || fe === "false" || ff == "false") {
  $('#EC8').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
 }

}
</script>
```

Edit: I just noticed a an error and thanks to the pointers i've updated my code so that the f vars look like this (as it should be && rather than || i think) but it still does not work - any more ideas?:

```
if (fa === false && fb === false && fb === false  && fc === false && fd === false && fe === false && ff == false)  {
     $('#EC8').show();
  $('#edialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
 }
```

I've created a JSFiddle (no working at all - i'm new to this!) here: http://jsfiddle.net/f5nwv4by/

Comment: Could you provide an [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the script and HTML? This so we can check reproduce it our self and create an fix

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle but i cannot get it to work at all in it :( http://jsfiddle.net/f5nwv4by/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from condition:

fa === <strike>"false"</strike>

Use this:

```
fa === false
```

Because `false` is Boolean value but `"false"` is string, and [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) returns Boolean value not string.

**Another mistake in your code:** You have mentioned `&` instead of `&&`

```
if (fa === "false" & fb === "false" || fb === "false"  || fc === "false" || fd === "false" || fe === "false" || ff == "false") {
                   ^
```

Reason: `&` **is bitwise AND**, and `&&` **is logical AND**

See: [Whats the difference between & and && in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Try this code:

```
if (fa === false || fb === false || fc === false || fd === false || fe === false || ff == false)  {
     $('#EC8').show();
     $('#edialog').dialog('open');
     return false;
 }
```

Working validation of checkboxes [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9k0ez3t/)

Comment: I've updated my code thanks but it's still submitting the form. Any more suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: ...i just checked and found an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined. I can't see anything referring to t?

Comment: Most welcome @BenWilliams. Hope you will try to debug your `Javascript/jquery`code using developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcefully matching the condition with its datatype too. So remove the `double quotes` from `false` and Use,

```
if (fa === false && fb === false || fb === false  || fc === false || fd === false || fe === false || ff == false) {
```

Read the difference [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: The difference is you used a single condition and I wrote the full `if condition` so got late little from you.

Comment: You have mistake in your code. You have copied OP's condition. Change `&` to `&&`.

Comment: Thanks - i've updated my code but its still submitting the form. I've added a JSFiddle so you can see the whole form etc...