# Whats does this if statement mean in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if (i & Math.pow(2,j))
```

I didn't get what the condition is doing and how it is working?
Is it equality?

Comment: This is syntactically wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6MTP2zn0

Comment: @AshiqurRahman can you add your code in the question itself?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6MTP2zn0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is building a binary code for `i` and it checks if a bit is set for the position of `j`:

```js
var i, j;
document.write('<pre>');
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        document.write(i & Math.pow(2, j) ? '*' : '_');
    }
    document.write('\n');
}
document.write('</pre>');
```