# Simple JavaScript issue?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have three values.

Each of those values is specified in a variable.

In the `if` statement I would like to state all these 3 values to be `true` in order for it to perform the `if` statement.

For example: `val == 'Millennium Wheel'` and `val2 = 'Palace of Westminster'` and then comes `val3`, all of these should be stated to be true before the if statement is applied.

Code is given below, thanks for your help.

```
function checkanagram() {
  var val = $("#anagramtext").val();
  var val2 = $("#anagramtext2").val();
  var val3 = $("#anagramtext3").val();
  if (val == 'Millennium Wheel') {
    alert('Correct Answer!');
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect answer, try again');
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between & and && in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: This is covered in any basic tutorial, and google search. Please utilize these great utilities :)

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

Just use the logical operator `&&` to require all 3 terms to be true. For example:

```
if (val == 'Millennium Wheel' && val2 == 'Palace of Westminster' && val3 == 'Buckingham Palace') {
    ....
}
```

Comment: There are 2 [equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). I had accidentally used strict equaiity (`===`) for `val3`. Try using `==` instead if `val3` needs to be converted to a string before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the bitwise **[Logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())** (`&&`).

In the following example, the correct answer will only be triggered when all three inputs have the value 'Millenium Wheel':

```js
function checkanagram() {
  var val = $("#anagramtext").val();
  var val2 = $("#anagramtext2").val();
  var val3 = $("#anagramtext3").val();
  if (val == 'Millennium Wheel' && val2 == val && val3 == val) {
    alert('Correct Answer!');
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect answer, try again');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="anagramtext"><br />
<input id="anagramtext2"><br />
<input id="anagramtext3"><br />
<button onclick="checkanagram()">Go!</button>
```

If you want to make it so that `val` must be `Millennium Wheel` while `val2` must be `Palace of Westminster`, and that `val3` can be anything, you can simply specify these requirements in the `AND` statement:

```js
function checkanagram() {
  var val = $("#anagramtext").val();
  var val2 = $("#anagramtext2").val();
  var val3 = $("#anagramtext3").val();
  if (val == 'Millennium Wheel' && val2 == 'Palace of Westminster' && val3) {
    alert('Correct Answer!');
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect answer, try again');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="anagramtext"><br />
<input id="anagramtext2"><br />
<input id="anagramtext3"><br />
<button onclick="checkanagram()">Go!</button>
```

Note that the absence of any equality for `val3` simply checks that **anything** is entered in that input.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the logical AND operator (&&) between each of the conditions:

```
function checkanagram(){
    var val = $("#anagramtext").val();
    var val2 = $("#anagramtext2").val();
    var val3 = $("#anagramtext3").val();

    if ((val == 'Millennium Wheel') && 
        (val2 == 'Palace of Westminster') && 
        (val3 == 'Wheel mum nine ill')) 
    {
        alert ('Correct Answer!');
    } else {
         alert ('Incorrect answer, try again');
    } 
}
```