# javascript if statement not evaluated as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Why my "C" condition go to 'else' statement?, they separated are going to 'if' statement but together are not working.

```
var objTest = {
    ID : "10"
};

//A: First Condition: Exist value in property ID
console.log((objTest.ID ? 'if' : 'else'));                      // output => "if"

//B: Second Condition: Value different from "0"
console.log((objTest.ID != "0" ? 'if' : 'else'));               // output => "if"

//C: First and Second Condition together must be "if" 
console.log((objTest.ID & objTest.ID != "0" ? 'if' : 'else'));  // output => "else"
```

Comment: There's a significant difference between `&` and `&&`

Comment: Also note that there is not really an `if` statement involved here.

Comment: Your faster than me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong `AND`opernator, you need to use `&&` instead of `&`:

```
console.log((objTest.ID && objTest.ID != "0" ? 'if' : 'else'));
```

The first `&`is a bitwise operator and `&&`is the logical operator.

Please take a look at **[What's the difference between & and && in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)** for further details.

Comment: Thanks!! that was the error! sorry! I only needed other programmer eyes

Comment: @CarlosDominguez this kind of confusion happens all the time ;)