# Order of statement evaluation

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
if (!caught.includes("AreYouHuman") && !caught.includes("pfail=1") && caught.includes("Episode") && caught.includes("Anime")) {
      var arraystring = caught.split("&s");
      var updating = chrome.tabs.update({url: arraystring[0] + "&s=beta&pfail=1"});
}
```

"caught" is a URL which I get from the browser.

1)would JavaScript stop at the first false statement it counters ( assuming that it iterates over them linearly ( AreYouHuman --> pfail=1 --> Episode -->Anime)).

2)or does it evaluate all of the statements at once then decide whether the whole thing is true or false ?

Assuming that 1) is the correct option, placing the least likely condition to be true,on the first position, would theoretically increase my code execution speed right ?

About the "duplicate" flag non-veteran programmers (like me) won't know "Short-circuit”  and probably are not looking for the difference between "&" and "&&", there search would be how does javascript evaluate booleans in an "if statement"

Comment: Lazy evaluation is one of the main principles of program executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the **[short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)** [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `&&`, yes, the entire expression will return `false` when the first of the expressions fails.

If, however, you were using a single `&`, then it would be a **[bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)** not be short-circuited and would continue to test the remaining conditions even if one were to return `false`.

The conditions are tested according to order of operations, but barring any grouping operators, the expression is evaluated left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, javascript interpreter stops at first false statement, from left to right. If a false value is encountered, it stops the tests, as the expression will evaluates to FALSE whatever the other values are