# Any alternative solution?

Tags: javascript

```
> let fullInteger = '';

const sentenceText = 'junayed';

for (let i = 0; i < sentenceText.length; i++) {
    if (sentenceText[i] == 'n' & sentenceText[i + 1] == 'a') {
        let newChar = sentenceText[i]
        newChar = 'a';
        fullInteger = fullInteger + newChar;
      
    }
    else if (sentenceText[i] == 'a' & sentenceText[i - 1] == 'n') {
        let newChar = sentenceText[i]
        newChar = 'n';
        fullInteger = fullInteger + newChar;
        
    }
    else{
        fullInteger = fullInteger + sentenceText[i];
    }
}
console.log(fullInteger);
```

It will take a string and change it if it finds "na" to "an". Does any of you know how can I shorten it, or any alternative idea?

Comment: so, you want to change all occurrences of `na` to `an`? `const fullInteger = sentenceText.split('na').join('an');`

Comment: If you could explain what you are trying to achieve, we could help in a better way

Comment: Please pay attention to the rules and guidelines of this site. Specifically [Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_ Adding #javascript to the end of your question title is not appropriate.

Comment: You can also look into regex: `const newStr = sentanceText.replace(/na/gi, 'an
')`. Note: the flags passed: `gi` have their meaning. `i` means case insensitivity. So `'na'` and `'NA'` both will be captured. `g` means global. So it will check for entire string for passed pattern

Comment: FYI `&` is not the same as `&&`. .......... `&` is bitwise. `&&` is the traditional as in boolean AND

Comment: @Rajesh - are you sure about the `i`? look at the code :p

Comment: Usually when you work with pattern, a following requirement is case-insensitivity. Hence I added `i`. I'll add explanation

Comment: Huh? look at the code in the question @Rajesh not some question somewhere you may have read :p

Comment: It is a good attempt at an algorithm I must say (Junayed). Despite its out of bounds  logical errors on `i - 1` and `i + 1`

Comment: @JaromandaX Point taken. Also, I have added a community answer, so if you wish, you may add you suggestion in it. Not adding mine as it has already been answered

Answer (score 1):

this should be a simple replace

```js
const sentenceText = 'junayed';
const sentenceText1 = 'junyed';

function replaceContent(sentence){
  return sentence.replace(/na/g,'an');
}


console.log(replaceContent(sentenceText));// gives "juanyed" - ie: 'na' has been replaced by 'an'

console.log(replaceContent(sentenceText1));// gives junyed - ie: no 'na' to be replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve this. Lets first try to use your algorithm:

Improvements:

- Suggestions by [GetSet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1780873/getset),

  - `&&` and not `&`: `&` means bitwise AND and double `&&` means the logical AND.
  - Error on `i-1` and `i+1`: If a string starts with `a` or ends with `n`, your code will break. You should add checks for them. You can so that as:

```
!!sentanceText[index]
```

---

**Other suggestions:**

- You do not need multiple assignments. Your second assignment makes first one void.

```
let newChar = sentenceText[i]
newChar = 'a';
```

- You so not need else if case. Since you have already checked for `[i] === 'n' && [i+1] === 'a'`, you can just set you `newChar = 'an'` and skip next iteration as it has been take care of. You can do that by incrementing `i`

```
if (sentenceText[i] == 'n' && sentenceText[i + 1] == 'a') {
  fullInteger = fullInteger + 'an';
  i++;
}
```

---

Following is a sample

```js
function getProcessedStr(sentenceText) {
  let fullInteger = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < sentenceText.length; i++) {
    if (sentenceText[i] === 'n' && !!sentenceText[i + 1] && sentenceText[i + 1] === 'a') {
      fullInteger = fullInteger + 'an';
      i++
    } else {
      fullInteger = fullInteger + sentenceText[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(fullInteger);
  return fullInteger
}

getProcessedStr('junayed');
getProcessedStr('junayedn');
```

#### References:

- [What's the difference between & and && in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)
- [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)