# Refactoring the ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I am quite stuck in a refactored ternary operator while learning react. Here is the code I came across inside a JSX:

```
{props.openSpots === 0 && <div className="card--badge">SOLD OUT</div>}
```

I would like to ask why this will return the card--badge div? I am only familiar with the complete common ternary operator that looks like this instead:

```
{props.openSpots === 0 ? <div className="card--badge">SOLD OUT</div> : null}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310120/3977134 help you?

Comment: You have and `a && b` statement here. It's not a ternary operator. It's logical "and"
This will return `b` if `a` is true, otherwise it will be false, and will simply return nothing.

This will return the `div` if `props.openSpots === 0`. Otherwise nothing will be rendered.

Comment: `&&` evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first falsy operand it encounters; _if all values are truthy, the value of the last operand is returned._

Comment: During the lesson it was first coded with the more familiar ternary operator then changed with the one I questioned above. This brought the confusion in me whether it is ternary operator or not -- or is it just a refactored one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` operator looks for the `second` argument if the `first` argument is `true`.

But, if `first` argument is `false` it does not look for `second` argument, and directly returns `false`.

`true` && statement == statement;

`false` && statement == false;

```js
console.log(
    true && "I am visible"
)
console.log(
   '  ' && "I am visible"
)

console.log(
    false && "I am not visible"
)
console.log(
    0 && "I am not visible"
)
console.log(
   null && "I am not visible"
)
console.log(
   undefined && "I am not visible"
)

console.log(
   true && '' && "I am not visible"
)
```

[Link for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#description)

Comment: Thanks @8bitIcon, edit is very helpful for the users. Found it really helpful. Will try to add links to the reference from next time.

Answer (score 1):

From the react documentation:

> It works because in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: imo this should be the accepted answer